# Absolute element breaking parent div layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my template, my range slider shows the value on top of the slide thumb, with a function I did to change the left of the bubble when the range slider value changes, but this is causing it to break my layout because there is a padding in the parent div

**A vertical scroll appears because of the size break:**

[image: break layout]

**How I wanted it to look:**

[image: wanted it to look]

```js
// Range Slider
var cash = document.getElementById("cashRange");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var bubble = document.getElementById("bubble");

cash.addEventListener("input", function() {
  setBubble(this, bubble);
});

function setBubble(range, bubble) {
  const val = range.value;
  const min = range.min ? range.min : 0;
  const max = range.max ? range.max : 100;
  const newVal = Number(((val - min) * 95.5) / (max - min));
  bubble.innerHTML = val;
  bubble.style.left = `calc(${newVal}% + (${9 - newVal * 0.15}px))`;
}
```

```css
.moneyStyle {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: flex-start;
padding: 0px 28px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
div#moneyTitle {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: row;
font-size: 15px;
color: #252729;
font-family: 'Roboto Regular';
}
  

  div#moneyContent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    transition: .3s;
    }
#rangeSlider {
width: 100%;
margin-top: 35px;
}
.range-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* to view extent of wrap */
  outline: 1px solid dodgerblue;
}

#bubble {
  background: transparent;
  color: black;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(0% + 9px);
  bottom: 20px;
  transform: translateX(-48%);
}

#bubble::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body style="padding:60px">
<div class="moneyStyle">      
<div id="moneyTitle">
<span>Down Payment</span>
</div>
<div id="moneyContent">
<div id="rangeSlider">
<div class="range-wrap">
<input type="range" min="0" max="10000" value="0" step="50" class="cash range" id="cashRange">
<output id="bubble">0</output>
</div>                                              
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I've copied your code into a working code snippet. Please edit the snippet so it demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: thank you very much, do you know of any solution that I could implement?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Please edit the code snippet until it demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I updated my doubt, it appears a vertical scroll now, this is what I want to remove, I don't want it to break the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `overflow-x: hidden;` CSS attribute to hide the scrollbar

Here is your code fixed

```html
<style>
.moneyStyle {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: flex-start;
padding: 0px 28px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
div#moneyTitle {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: row;
font-size: 15px;
color: #252729;
font-family: 'Roboto Regular';
}
  

  div#moneyContent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow-x: hidden;

    transition: .3s;
    }
#rangeSlider {
width: 100%;
margin-top: 35px;
}
.range-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* to view extent of wrap */
  outline: 1px solid dodgerblue;
}

#bubble {
  background: transparent;
  color: black;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(0% + 9px);
  bottom: 20px;
  transform: translateX(-48%);
}

#bubble::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}</style>
<body style="padding:60px">
<div class="moneyStyle">      
<div id="moneyTitle">
<span>Down Payment</span>
</div>
<div id="moneyContent">
<div id="rangeSlider">
<div class="range-wrap">
<input type="range" min="0" max="10000" value="0" step="50" class="cash range" id="cashRange" style="width: 100%">
<output id="bubble">0</output>
</div>                                              
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
// Range Slider
var cash = document.getElementById("cashRange");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var bubble = document.getElementById("bubble");

cash.addEventListener("input", function() {
  setBubble(this, bubble);
});

function setBubble(range, bubble) {
  const val = range.value;
  const min = range.min ? range.min : 0;
  const max = range.max ? range.max : 100;
  const newVal = Number(((val - min) * 95.5) / (max - min));
  bubble.innerHTML = val;
  bubble.style.left = `calc(${newVal}% + (${9 - newVal * 0.15}px))`;
}
</script>
```

---

Consider trying this code (It's different from yours):

```js
const
  range = document.getElementById('range'),
  rangeV = document.getElementById('rangeV'),
  setValue = ()=>{
    const
      newValue = Number( (range.value - range.min) * 100 / (range.max - range.min) ),
      newPosition = 10 - (newValue * 0.2);
    rangeV.innerHTML = `<span>${range.value}</span>`;
    rangeV.style.left = `calc(${newValue}% + (${newPosition}px))`;
  };
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setValue);
range.addEventListener('input', setValue);
```

```css
body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 10vh;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: #03a9f4;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #03a9f4;
}
.range-wrap{
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
.range-value{
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
}
.range-value span{
  width: 30px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #03a9f4;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.range-value span:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid #03a9f4;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Input Range with Dynamic Label</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="range-wrap">
    <div class="range-value" id="rangeV"></div>
    <input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="3000" value="0" step="1">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had overflowed the parent div, so it was overlapping, thanks for the solution, it helped a lot